# Unable to Change Primary Site Collection adminstrator SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, powershell, central-administration

I have an issue where I cannot change the primary site collection administrator of a site which is set to my user account.

In the central administration console when changing the name I get the error:

[image]

Running the `set-spsite` command in powershell it is indicating that it is a `NullReferenceException`.

any ideas on how to resolve this will be very much appreciated.

EDIT

> 02/28/2019 14:43:06.79    w3wp.exe (0x53EC)                           0x36CC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (POST:http://server:5000/_admin/owners.aspx))
>
> 02/28/2019 14:43:06.79    w3wp.exe (0x53EC)                           0x36CC  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (POST:http://server:5000/_admin/owners.aspx)   026d2244-b9f2-4b83-83a3-0837e178a172
>   02/28/2019 14:43:06.79    w3wp.exe (0x53EC)                           0x36CC  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  026d2244-b9f2-4b83-83a3-0837e178a172
>
> 02/28/2019 14:43:06.79    w3wp.exe (0x53EC)                           0x36CC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (PostAuthenticateRequestHandler). Execution Time=3.90652513934052   026d2244-b9f2-4b83-83a3-0837e178a172
>   02/28/2019 14:43:06.82  w3wp.exe (0x53EC)                           0x36CC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         g8ga    Medium      Begin Query the AD to get the user email and display name.  026d2244-b9f2-4b83-83a3-0837e178a172
>   02/28/2019 14:43:06.82  w3wp.exe (0x53EC)                           0x36CC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         g8gb    Medium      End Query the AD to get the user email and display name.    026d2244-b9f2-4b83-83a3-0837e178a172
>
> 02/28/2019 14:43:06.83    w3wp.exe (0x53EC)                           0x36CC  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser.set_IsSiteAdmin(Boolean value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.set_Owner(SPUser value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteAdministration.set_OwnerLoginName(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.OwnersPage.BtnConfirm_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  026d2244-b9f2-4b83-83a3-0837e178a172

Comment: can you check the ULS logs for the correlation id mentioned in message?

Comment: Hi Waqas I have ammeded the post above by entering the ULS log as well it looks to be failing in the isSiteAdmin function

Comment: is user profile conntected to web application? make sure site is not locked or quota is not full?

Comment: Have you tried updating the site admin using the -force switch?

Comment: Waqas the site is not locked,  and is well under the quota,  the issue I believe is with the user Currently in the Primary SCA which was an account which was recreated.  Christoffer the -Force switch is not working and throwing a Paramater set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters which I believe indicates that the switch is not valid for changing the owneralias

Comment: user recreated? deleted in active directory then recreated?

Comment: yes that is correct by my understanding at least

Comment: then looks like the existing id become orphan....do you have test user? you have to migrate user command...

Comment: something like this ?

$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\JaneDoe" -Web http://webUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "Domain\JaneSmith" -IgnoreSid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed running the Move-SPUser command to a temporary account and then running the same command back again fixed the issue,

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\JaneDoe" -Web http://webUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "Domain\JaneSmith" -IgnoreSid
```

This is taken from

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps

Thank you Waqas for pointing me in the right direction